# What is the return type of Regex.Split(s, @"\W+"); in C#?

Tags: c#

What is the return type of Regex.Split?

Comment: as you can see from the responses, MSDN is a great tool for questions like this. don't get discouraged by losing point, live and learn :)

Answer (score 13):

A `string[]` according to [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ze12yx1d.aspx). But I think you should learn how to either [google that](http://www.google.com/search?q=regex.split) yourself, see it in visual studio (write it and hover your mouse over the function (Split)) or determine it in [reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).

Answer (score 3):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx) can be your friend.

```
public static string[] Split(
    string input,
    string pattern
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string[]
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx